# WSL - Can't login or pull image from an azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I have set up [WSL](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly). And then installed docked following this [tutorial](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/setting-up-docker-for-windows-and-wsl-to-work-flawlessly) and then installed azure cli.
I can login from windows command line; but I cannot login to azure container registry by using the command below from bash

```
$ az acr login --name $ACRNAME
```

I get the following error

> Error response from daemon: Get https://ACRNAME.azurecr.io/v2/:
>   unauthorized: authentication required

And also if i tried to pull the image by

```
$ docker pull ${ACRNAME}.azurecr.io/image_name
```

get the same error

> Error response from daemon: Get https://ACRNAME.azurecr.io/v2/:
>   unauthorized: authentication required

But i am able to see the list. The following command returns list

```
$ az acr repository list -n $ACRNAME
```

I have found [this closed issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/958) and change my machine DNS server to 8.8.8.8 but no progress. What am i missing?

Comment: You can check your username and password which you choose to login. You can get the information in portal, container->access keys.

Comment: This actually looks like the `$` may have been left off of the command.  Have you checked that you referenced the bash variable properly?

Comment: @twitchax yes variables are alright, I have tried without using any variable

Comment: @Charles-MSFT thanks for pointing this. I was using the wrong user name, I am happy to accept if you add this as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For you issue, you maybe use the wrong username and password. So, first you can check your username and password which you choose to login. You can get the information in portal: container->Access keys.

You can get more information from this document [`az acr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-check-name) with [`az acr check-name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-check-name) and [`az acr create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-create).

Comment: I was getting the same `Error response from daemon: Get https://ACRNAME.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required` described above on a newly created ACR instance.  Triple checked login server names, user name, passwords (tried both), and no joy. 

I regenerated they keys (passwords) and then it worked.

`az acr credential renew -n ACRNAME  --password-name password
az acr credential renew -n ACRNAME  --password-name password2
az acr credential show -n ACRNAME --query "{Username:username, Password1:passwords[0].value, Password2:passwords[1].value}" -o table`